# Connection DB in golang

Tags: model-view-controller, go, init

Where i can put initialize files like languages, connection db etc. in mvc structur golang (beego,revel)?

I tried to use in controller but it isn't good.

Is a good solution would be create base controller and put here all init connection, languages etc? or is there some other way (better)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use global variables, but I don't suggest to do it. What happens in more complicated applications where database logic is spread over multiple packages? It's better to use dependency injection:

File: main.go

```
package main

import (
    "bookstore/models"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type Env struct {
    db *sql.DB
}

func main() {
    db, err := models.NewDB("postgres://user:pass@localhost/bookstore")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    env := &Env{db: db}

    http.HandleFunc("/books", env.booksIndex)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}

func (env *Env) booksIndex(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != "GET" {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(405), 405)
        return
    }
    bks, err := models.AllBooks(env.db)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
        return
    }
    for _, bk := range bks {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s, %s, %s, £%.2f\n", bk.Isbn, bk.Title, bk.Author, bk.Price)
    }
}
```

File: models/db.go

```
package models

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func NewDB(dataSourceName string) (*sql.DB, error) {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", dataSourceName)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return db, nil
}
```

Comment: This is from a blog post by Alex Edwards: https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/organising-database-access

Answer (score 1):

I always do some packega where i keep my enviroment variables.

For example `main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
     env "github.com/vardius/example/enviroment"
)

func main() {
    //some extra code here, http srever or something
    defer env.DB.Close()
}
```

end inside `enviroment` dir `env.go`

```
package env

import (
    "database/sql"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

var (
    DB     *sql.DB
)

func connectToDB(dbURL string) *sql.DB {
    conn, err := sql.Open("mysql", dbURL)
    //check for err

    return conn
}

func init() {
    DB = connectToDB("root:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test")
}
```

this way you initialize once your DB and can use it in all parts of your app by injecting env

> Ofcourse this solution has some downsides. First, code is harder to
>   ponder because the dependencies of a component are unclear. Second,
>   testing these components is made more difficult, and running tests in
>   parallel is near impossible. With global connections, tests that hit
>   the same data in a backend service could not be run in parallel.

There is a great article about a [Dependency Injection with Go](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/dependency-injection-with-go/)

I hope you will find this helpfull